# Google App Engine Flexible weekly update - how it works?

Tags: app-engine-flexible

As documented, the App Engine Flexible instances are restarted on a weekly basis for updates.
This is a problem because I have configured the environment with a minimum of 1 instance active, then when the weekly update occurs I found that there is a period where my service has 0 instances active (because the time needed for the creation of a new instance is greater than the time needed for the shutdown of my only active instance).

My questions are:

1. The weekly update is not fixed in time. Maybe there is a range in time in which I should expect the reboot of the instances? (ie: every friday during the night)
2. The weekly update involves all the instances, independently from when them were created? (ie: an instance created 1 hour or 1 day before the weekly update will be restarted?)
3. Is there any way to start an instance manually (ie: with a command, or calling an url), keeping the autoscaling policy? Normally the policy is the same used in the Autoscaler for Compute Engine, so based on CPU, Request or Stackdriver metrics.

Comment: Flexible environment is meant to be complementary to Standard. Take a look at https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/flexible-for-standard-users#when_to_use_the_flexible_environment

Answer (score 1):

1.- At this moment there is no way to know when the weekly restart is going to happen. GCP determine when is necessary and it does the restart of certain instances (once per week).

2.- No, as long as you have more than 1 one instance running you won’t see all of them being restarted at the same time.

What Google recommend to avoid downtime due to weekly restarts is having more than 1 instance as a minimum instance. Try to set at least 2 instances as a minimum.

I hope you find this information useful to others.

Answer (score 0):

1. There is no precise timeframe for the weekly restart.
2. The way it should work is to restart instance by instance, thus, it is recommended to have at least 2 instances. This is because the weekly restart restarts the whole VM.
3. Unfortunately, there isn't.